# Replacing variables in text with random values

Tags: php

I have a block of text that contains a variable:

```
Hello my name is john #last#
```

I have 20 different last names in a array that can be used, how can I replace #last# with a random last name from the array? Meaning how can I read between the #'s and get "last" then use that to determine which array to grab from and input a random value

Comment: is this a homework question?  If it is Jamal, give it a homework tag for people to give you extra help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) could be your friend.

Basic example:

```
$s="Hello my name is John #last#";

function random_name($m) {
    $a=array('Fos', 'Smith', 'Metzdenafbuhrer', 'the Enlightened');
    foreach ($m as $match) {
        return $a[array_rand($a)];
    }
}

$news=preg_replace_callback('/#last#/', 'random_name', $s);
```

**UPDATE:** I created another example for you, with more flexibility:

```
$s="Hello #title#, my name is John #last#";

function random_name($m) {
    $a=array(
        'last' => array('Fos', 'Smith', 'Metzdenafbuhrer', 'the Enlightened'),
        'title' => array('Honey', 'Boss', ', I am your father'),
        );
    foreach ($m as $match) {
        $v=trim($match, '#');
        return $a[$v][array_rand($a[$v])];
    }
}

$news=preg_replace_callback('/(#[a-z]+#)/', 'random_name', $s);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! The only thing is the words between the #'s can be about 5 different ones, is it possible to use wildcard between #'s and grab the text to see which array to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can user [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) like

```
<?php
    $str = 'Hello my name is john %s';
    printf($str, $name);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$random_last_names = array("Smith", "Jones", "Davis");
$string = "Hello my name is john #last#";

$random_last_name_id = rand(0, count($random_last_names));

$new_string = preg_replace("/#last#/", $random_last_names[$random_last_name_id], $string);
?>
```

Or better yet, use printf like fabrik said, but you can use this rand() method to select a name.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `preg_replace` with the `/e` `PREG_REPLACE_EVAL` modifier:

```
$str = '...' // your input text
$names = array('smith', 'brown', 'white', 'red');

echo preg_replace('/#last#/e', '$names[rand(0, count($names) - 1)]', $str);
```